# JPA or Hibernates With Oracle Table Partitions?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I need to use an Entity framework with my application, and I have used table - partitions in Oracle database. With simple JDBC, I am able to select data from a specific partition. But I don't know whether I can do the same with hibernate or Eclipse link (JPA). If someone knows how to do that, please do let me know.

usually the select statement in JDBC - SQL is,

```
select * from TABLE_NAME partiton(PARTITON_NAME) where FIELD_NAME='PARAMETER_VALUE';
```

How can I do the same with Hibernates or JPA?

Please share at least a link for learning sources.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA or any other ORM framework does not support Oracle partition tables natively (atleast in my knowledge).

There are different possible solutions though, depending on the nature of your problem:

- Refactor your classes so that data that needs to be treated differently in real-life, belongs in a separate class. Sometimes this is called vertical partitioning (partitions are not obtained across rows, rather across columns).
- Use Oracle partition tables underneath and use native SQL queries or stored procedures from JPA. This is just a possibile solution (I haven't attempted this).
- Use [Hibernate Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html). Although the typical use case for Hibernate Shards is not for a single database, it presents a singular view of distributed databases to an application developer.

**Related**:

1. [JPA Performance, Don't Ignore the Database](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/08/28/jpa-performance-dont-ignore-database-0)

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. Is this the article? https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-performance-dont-ignore

Answer (score 2):

*EclipseLink* supports partitioning or sharding with different options.

You can find more about this and examples here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Data_Partitioning

Answer (score 1):

Table partitioning is data organization on physical level. In a word, partitioning is a poor man index. Like the later, it is supposed to be entirely transparent to the user. A SQL query is allowed to refer to the entire table, but not partition. Then, it is query optimizer job to decide if it can leverage a certain partition, or index.

Comment: You can only throw so much processing power on a single DB server. At some point you'll need to scale out, for performance, reliability or cost. Sharding is one possible solution to this.