# JPA, Is it possible to map one class to multiple tables with the same structure but different names?

Tags: spring, jpa

I need to record every day's information, like the food price, so I created almost infinite tables named with the same pattern as `food_${date}`, like `food_20180222`, `food_20180223`, and etc.

Each table has the same structure as follows

```
+----+-------+--+
| Id | Price |  |
+----+-------+--+
|  1 |    10 |  |
+----+-------+--+
```

I wonder that by using Spring JPA, is it possible to map one `food` entity to those tables with different names? Or can `food` entity be dynamically mapped to one of the tables determined by `date`?

Comment: Why would you like to divide them into separate tables in the first place?

Comment: Oh, just an example @MateuszMrozewski

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699974/jpa-or-hibernates-with-oracle-table-partitions

Comment: No. Just no. A class maps to 1 primary table